# Bind SyncAdapter service to Activity

Tags: android, android-service, android-syncadapter, android-service-binding, syncservices

I'm currently working with a SyncAdapter that syncs data every 15 minutes. Is it possible to bind that Service to the Activity so I can show the user what the currenty sync status is?

I read in the documentation about IPC between services and activities that you can communicate with Messengers and Handlers. But I can't return a mMessenger.getBinder() in my SyncService onBind method because I have to return the syncAdapter.getSyncAdapterBinder() because of the SyncAdapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a different `IBinder`, depending on the action that was set for the `Intent`. Check out my response to [Android SyncAdapter: how to get notified of specific sync happened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35147093/android-syncadapter-how-to-get-notified-of-specific-sync-happened/35147834#35147834)

Comment: Thanks @Marten. This could work and is probably the solution. I'll try and implement that and I'll get back to you on that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this definetiley work.

```
public class SyncService extends Service {

private static SyncAdapter sSyncAdapter = null;

private static final Object sSyncAdapterLock = new Object();

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    synchronized (sSyncAdapterLock) {
        if (sSyncAdapter == null) {
            sSyncAdapter = new SyncAdapter(getApplicationContext(), true);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return sSyncAdapter.getSyncAdapterBinder();
}
}
```

Comment: I have it like that now. But i need to return mMessenger.getBinder() to handle communication between the activtiy and service. Here is the doc:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger